# How do you pause the game to issue orders?

Tags: warhammer-40k-dawn-of-war-ii

In Dawn of War 2 and DoW2 Retribution, how do you pause the game to issue orders?  I have seen it done in let's play commentaries but cannot find the key-binding.

Comment: The `F10` key brings up the menu, is that what you're referring to?

Answer (score 4):

As Shadur mentioned, bringing up the menu in the game will pause the display.  Despite the menu being in the way, you can still issue commands to your units and they will be executed once you unpause.  source: http://www.pcgamer.com/forum/showthread.php?t=5529‎

Answer (score 0):

The <kbd>pause</kbd>/<kbd>break</kbd> key on your keyboard.