# Does Dawn of War's single player mode have an active pause?

Tags: warhammer-40k-dawn-of-war

Is there active pause<sup>1</sup> in *Dawn of War* single player mode?

---

## Context / "Show Your Research"

I played the demo for *Warhammer 40k: Dawn of War*, but unfortunately I didn't check for active pause before uninstalling it. As reinstallation would be a bit of a hassle, I searched the Internet, but unfortunately the existing information seems a bit... murky.

- There's [this thread on Steam forums](https://steamcommunity.com/app/285190/discussions/0/2579854400740643158/) where you can learn that "there has always been"/"there has never been" an active pause in *Dawn of War* series.
- An [analogous question for the game's sequel](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/116831/how-do-you-pause-the-game-to-issue-orders) indicates in *DoW II* active pause is a bug and might not be *all that playable*.

So, to reiterate the question: is there active pause in *Dawn of War*? <sub>(And is it an actual feature, ie. can you comfortably play the game with it, unlike in *DoW II* where the menu is blocking your view?)</sub>

---

<sup>1</sup> Active pause - feature in real time games that enables the player to pause the game in order to issue commands that will get carried out once the game is unpaused.

Comment: There is because i was playing it recently and was timing a 2 lane advance in the second mission though. though i can not confirm if it is a big or not as per your second link but it doesn't seem top cause problems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes- I just tested it. You can pause with the pause-break key and give orders while the game is paused, which are carried out when you unpause.

The Paused notification is unobtrusive white text that doesn't get in the way.